# The namespace "TypeProviders" is not defined (open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, f#

I'm walking through Visual Studio's F# tutorial project.  When I uncomment the "OData" module (which is very simple, similar to this [MSDN walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156504.aspx)), the first line here

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

type Northwind = ODataService<"http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/">

// ...
```

indicates this compiler error:

> The namespace "TypeProviders" is not defined

The error remains after adding a reference to "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders" and "System.Data.Services.Client".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @abatishchev no compiler warnings, apparently... there is another error that does not seem related to resolving the library reference:  `The type provider 'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders' reported an error: Error reading schema. The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.`

Comment: try open FSharp.Data instead Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

Comment: @Alex "FSharp..." is the name of the assembly, the namespace is "Microsoft.FSharp..." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362324.aspx

Comment: okay, maybe it's because I used Freebase Provider from this library: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/, but it doesn't include OData.

Comment: install FSharp.Data.TypeProviers nuget. Probably you're missing some reference, maybe policy.2.3.FSharp.Core

Comment: @Alex no luck still. It did seem to add an updated version of FSharp.Core and FSharp.Data.TypeProviders, but the error message is the same.

Comment: I just created new project, added this nuget to it and open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

Comment: just create new project

Comment: oy ... thanks @Alex, that did the trick.  Will accept if you want to post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you need to create new project, then add FSharp.Data.TypeProviers nuget to this project and the following code should work:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
type Northwind = ODataService<"http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/">
```